# How do I mock a function that is defined within another function in python pytest with magic mock framework?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-mock, pytest-mock

Considering the following peace of code:

```
class X:
   def func_a(a):
      //function does somthing
      def func_b(b):
         // do something
      func_b(a)
```

How can I mock function func_b(a) in my test?

```
with patch('x.func_a.func_b', side_effect=mock_func_b)
```

Does not work. I am only able to mock func_a. How can I handle this issue?

Comment: You can't. `func_b` is not available outside of `func_a` just like any local variable.

Comment: So, I have to decide to make my code a little bit more ugly in order to be able to mock things in pytest? that is really bad ...

Comment: Really, defining a function inside a function is for very specific things, like capturing values from the outer function in an instance of the inner function (closure). If you're not doing that then you might consider putting the thing into a class.

Comment: It would help if you showed a real code sample. It's hard to know what a good approach to design might be without that.